# MongoDB high page faults every 15 minutes, delayed readers

Tags: performance, mongodb

We have a relatively small MongoDB production replicaset. We do about 100 operations per second -- balanced reads and writes.

Every 15 minutes or so we see a spike in response time on reads, and in mongostat we can see high page faults at the same time. An example below:

`insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults      locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn              set repl       time
   106     56    103     *0     111   136|0       0   528g  1057g  1.35g     57    adcore:3.0%          0       0|0     0|0    99k   130k   140 prod_replication  PRI   12:59:39
    90     39     83     *0      94   100|0       0   528g  1057g  1.35g     40    adcore:2.1%          0       0|0     0|0    73k    80k   140 prod_replication  PRI   12:59:40
   108     57     93     *0     102   116|0       0   528g  1057g  1.36g     49    adcore:3.2%          0       0|0     0|0    90k   110k   140 prod_replication  PRI   12:59:41
   104     43     94     *0     103   120|0       0   528g  1057g  1.35g     47    adcore:3.0%          0       0|0     0|0    84k    99k   140 prod_replication  PRI   12:59:42
    92     51     83     *0     102   119|0       0   528g  1057g  1.36g     72    adcore:3.8%          0       0|0     0|0    80k    92k   140 prod_replication  PRI   12:59:43
    95     45     87     *0     100   118|0       0   528g  1057g  1.36g    968    adcore:3.0%          0       0|0     1|0    81k    88k   141 prod_replication  PRI   12:59:44
    27     17     39     *0      28    32|0       0   528g  1057g  1.37g   2294    adcore:0.8%          0      32|4     1|3    24k    36k   141 prod_replication  PRI   12:59:45
   198     88    160     *0     115   130|0       0   528g  1057g  1.37g    944     admin:0.4%          0       0|0     0|0   139k   177k   140 prod_replication  PRI   12:59:46
    98     49     89     *0     115   127|0       0   528g  1057g  1.37g     41    adcore:3.2%          0       0|0     0|0    87k    97k   140 prod_replication  PRI   12:59:47
    95     45     81      3     101   114|0       0   528g  1057g  1.37g     49    adcore:2.5%          0       0|0     0|0    82k    96k   140 prod_replication  PRI   12:59:48`

(sorry for the poor formatting)

It's interesting that MongoDB is interacting with the admin database at the same time, which we don't see most of the time.

I realise faults are simply MongoDB going to disk. Am looking for suggestions how to track down why the faults are so heavy periodically and if there's any tuning we can do to reduce this, because we see max response times spike from 20ms to 1600ms which is unacceptible.

Any input welcome.

Comment: You might find greater insight into exactly what is happening with mtools (see this blog post) http://blog.mongodb.org/post/85123256973/introducing-mtools and you should ensure you have all the OS settings in line with https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/ These would be good starting points.

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB are you using, and what sort of deployment do you have (standalone, replica set, sharded cluster)? I would review the `mongod` logs around the time you are seeing increased page faults. If there isn't anything obvious at the default log level I would increase the logging for [query components](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/log-messages/#QUERY) if there isn't anything obvious). If slowdown is recurring every 15 minutes I'd suspect some sort of scheduled process running in your environment (eg. data ingestion or backup).

Comment: Thanks for input so far. We notice that this issue almost always occurs alongside a flush operation, so we are working on the assumption that the flush in these minutes is taking longer than expected. But we don't have a reason for why some flushes would take much longer than others. Our mean flush time is 160ms.

Comment: Are you using MMAPv1 engine on Windows OS? Have you tried to install [KB2731284](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2731284) according to MongoDB production notes [recommendation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#install-hotfix-for-mongodb-2-6-6-and-later)?

Comment: We are experiencing the exact same issue. I was wondering if you managed to resolve this phenomenon and what the cause was?